# How to implement Hashable struct for Image in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, hashable

I am working on chat view using swiftui. I do have the hashable struct as below

```
struct ChatMessage : Hashable {
    var message: String
    var isMe: Bool
    var avatar: String
}
```

It is working fine. But if i change the avatar data type to Image then i am getting error message as  **"Type 'ChatMessage' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'"**

```
struct ChatMessage : Hashable {
    var message: String
    var isMe: Bool
    var avatar: Image
}
```

How do i include the object (image) in struct that confirms Hashable.

Comment: I recommend to add an unique `id` and use (only) that as hash value.

Comment: I think you'll have to create your own type e.g. `HashableImage` that uses the `Hashable` protocol of Swift. Here is the official documentation of Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable

Answer (score 4):

SwiftUI `Image` is opaque struct that does not conform to `Hashable` protocol and does not provide any properties to use for custom hash, so you can either ignore it in your model hash (non-desirable) or use model in the way that some information about image take part in hash (much preferable).

Case a) - ignoring

```
struct ChatMessage : Hashable {

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(message)
        hasher.combine(isMe)
    }

    var message: String
    var isMe: Bool
    var avatar: Image
}
```

Case b) - including

```
struct ChatMessage : Hashable {

    var message: String
    var isMe: Bool
    var avatarName: String // avatar's name included in hash automatically

    var avatar: Image { // calculable property not used by hashing
       Image(avatarName)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good insight, but there is one issue with case B - you lose the ability to use the other Image's initializers like `Image(systemName:)`.